# Is it possible to give up class feature twice for archetypes, if you have it double?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class, archetype

For example: the ranger [trapper](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo---ranger-archetypes/trapper) gets trap finding, the rogue [counterfeit-mage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/archetypes/paizo---rogue-archetypes/counterfeit-mage) gives up trapfinding (not trap sense) - could the player select another archetype that replaces trapfinding?

If you started the game at level two as  1 Trapper / 1 Counterfeit-mage+other archetype your trapper can't disarm magical traps - without the awkwardness of having been able to do so in the past and suddenly not after dipping in rogue of all classes :D

What if the replaced feature can be bought with a feat when the time comes.

Say a Oracle  [Community Guardian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/halfling/community-guardian-oracle-halfling) and [Psychic Searcher](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/archetypes/paizo---oracle-archetypes/psychic-searcher), which only overlap on the Revelation gained at 3rd level. If the player locked the feat he gains at third level to go towards paying for the extra [revelation feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-revelation-1), could he take both archetypes?

I'm looking for rules as written answers, but am curious about RAI, if there's evidence for it, such as a designer's comment.

I'd also appreciate a side-note based on GM experience as to the estimated threat to balance and whether you'd allow it.

Comment: I have strongly considered allowing the use of a feat like that to do a "double replacement", mostly because the ACG classes have very few compatible archetypes (because they both replace the same generic, repeatable class feature at the same level) and lots of interesting potential combinations.  I have not tried it because while I might have bent the rules like that for a player, doing so for "DMPCs" when I'm running multiple (it's a small party) felt like an abuse of my GM powers, not because of any balance concerns.

Comment: If you were concerned about balance, maybe start doing it for enemy npcs first and see how that goes? If it seems fine open it up to everyone else. Then if the players accept (and hopefully use) it, you should be golden.

But I could see why if you changed it only so you can get what you want on your GM PC it would risk seeming off.

Answer (score 6):

Per [Class Archetypes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/class-archetypes):

> A character can take more than one archetype and garner additional alternate class features, but none of the alternate class features can replace or alter **the same class feature from the base class** as another alternate class feature. For example, a fighter could not be both an armor master and a brawler, since both archetypes replace the weapon training 1 class feature with something different.

(emphasis mine)

That is the only paragraph which references multiple archetypes, and it talks about replacing/altering a feature from a single base class.

Therefore, RAW appears to be yes: if you're multi-classing and both of your classes give you evasion, you can take archetypes of both classes which both change/replace evasion: the rogue archetype affects the rogue-granted evasion, and the barbarian archetype affects the barbarian-granted evasion. The character could *not*, however, take two rogue archetypes which both affect evasion: the second rogue archetype would "replace or alter the same class feature from the base class" as the first had already altered.

Similarly, an Oracle cannot, under RAW, take both the Community Guardian and Psychic Searcher archetypes: they both affect the 3rd level Revelation. Under RAW, there is no way around this. As a GM, I would strongly consider allowing this particular pairing at the cost of the feat, but that would clearly be a house rule.

Comment: I'm curious--what about that oracle combination makes it worth a feat? Is that carefully considered or a random suggestion?

Comment: ... mostly a random suggestion; if a player came to me and said "I'd like to use these two archetypes; if I burn a feat, can I do it?", I'd be inclined to say "yes" for those two particular archetypes. I'd have to read them a _lot_ more closely to determine whether I'd require the feat.

Comment: Worth it, is a question of perspective. I think the "Inspire" ability gained at 2nd level is worth a feat, and I would take Community Guardian only oherwise, because it works with the build (a supporter helpful halfling Oradin).

Comment: I just realized that it's been misunderstood as burning an additional feat. The feat wasn't burnt, just spent (i.e. on the feat "Extra Revelation")